# Finding the square root of a number

Tags: assembly, easy68k

I want to know how would you find the square root in the EASy68k assembler.

I know it's a function but I don't know the code for it.

I want to find the Square root of 72.

The answer should be an integer so 8 in this case.

I found this algorithm:

```
value-->c1 
loop: 
value/c1-->c2 
(c1+c2)/2-->c1 
until c1=c2 
c1-->result
```

I converted this into 68k code:

```
    move.w #72,d2  ; value = 64
    move.l d2,d5   ; c1 = 64
    move.l d5,d3   ; hold d3 = 64
LOOP
    divs d2,d3     ; value/c1  
    move.l d3,d6   ; move answer above to c2 = d6
    add.l d5,d6    ; add c1+c2
    divs #2,d6
    move.l d6,d5   ; move the answer above it do d4 = c1
    cmp.l d6,d5
    beq loop

    move.l d5,d7   ; d7 will have the result
```

And it doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The division at the beginning of your loop will not divide `value` by `c1` except on the very first iteration. Since your `value` is in `d2` and `c1` is in `d5` you should replace:

```
divs d2,d3     ; value/c1  
move.l d3,d6   ; move answer above to c2 = d6
```

with:

```
move.l d2,d1   ; temp = value
divs d5,d1     ; temp /= c1
move.l d1,d6   ; d6 = value / c1
```

I found it unclear whether you're using `divs.w` or `divs.l`. If you're using `divs.w` you'll have to keep in mind that `d1` will contain both the quotient and the remainder after the division.